# Newslist stopped working after upgrade to 4.2 version

Tags: impresspages

After upgrade to 4.2 version ImpressPages - NewsList Module has stopped working:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Ip\Internal\Text\Html2Text::get_text() in /mysite.com/Plugin/NewsList/HelperPageContents.php on line 127.
```

I know, NewsList plugin has upgrade to 1.05v but
after upgraded to this version, there is still the same problem.

Should look like the upgrade procedure?

Comment: I see. May be the update package build has failed :| looking.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. There is no such code in recent version. But I've found other bugs that may occur if you have invalid HTML or other content related issues. They all have been fixed and released under 1.06 version. Please update and let me know how it goes.

Cheers.

Comment: At first look works great! Tomorrow check it carefully. Thanks for the quick response.